# Show first and last name instead of JID

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I'm working on a chat using XMPP.

And when I try to load the users with their names who are part of the roster on XMPP, it always shows only the username, which is the JID, instead of the name although I specified that I want to retrieve the name attribute with the following:

```
var jid = $(this).attr('jid');
var name = $(this).attr('name');
```

And I did specify in the System Properties under Server Manager in Openfire the following:

```
jdbcUserProvider.nameField    -->   first_name

nameField                     -->   first_name
```

But it keeps on showing me the user's username, which is the JID that is registered in the DB.